# How to write array into file with column seperated values

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a 2d int array. I want it to be written in a CSV file. I used the following code

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filecsv.csv"));
for(int index11 = 0; index11 < a.length; index11++) {
    for(int subIndex1 = 0; subIndex1 < 2; subIndex1++) {
        writer.write(a[index11][subIndex1]); 
        System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

My output should be like

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

but nothing is written in my CSV file and also in the console window nothing gets printed. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Whats happening?Any errors?

Comment: does `writer.flush();writer.close();` after your code might help?

Comment: Doesn't `writer.close()` automatically call `writer.flush()`?

Comment: at least `System.out.print(",");` should print, if not your array is empty. On the other hand, you write the data to the file and the separator to console, you will not be getting a `csv` with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try{      

     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filecsv.csv"));
           for(int index11 = 0; index11 < a.length; index11++) {
               for(int subIndex1 = 0; subIndex1 < 2; subIndex1++){
                   writer.write(String.valueOf(a[index11][subIndex1])); 
                   if(subIndex1<2-1){
                       writer.write(",");

                    }
               }
               writer.write("\n");
          }
}
    catch(IOException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        writer.close();
```

Comment: I tried the above code .. In the Csv File instead of array contents, "?" is only printed. But When I print the same array in console I am able to see the values. Why is it so?. Can u please explain?

Comment: @Praveen This problem occurs when you try to write a `int` into csv.. Convert that int value into String and then write in file.. See the updated code above

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. You're printing the numbers to the file, but the commas and newlines to the console (`System.out`).
2. You're printing an additional comma at the end of each line.
3. You need to add `writer.close()` at the end, otherwise the characters are just going to sit in the buffer and not get written at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing an array of "," to the console according to your code **System.out.print(",");**. Also, I doubt you should do a flush, and after you finish writing the content, you should close the writer as well as the file. Though I haven't tryied to write a csv file before, but these are common steps to write into files and save the file.